# Can we bypass the limit of 10000 rows of BigQuery Data Connector?

Tags: google-bigquery

i'm trying to export bigquery content to a sheet but by default bigquery has a limit of 10k ROWS max that you can import to a sheet, is there another way to export all that data without having to get the limit of 10k rows ?

thanks.

Comment: Wondering: How much data do you want to put on a sheet? Those have limitations too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 approaches that you can consider:

1. To use [BigQuery Connector](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/g-suite/connecting-bigquery-and-google-sheets-to-help-with-hefty-data-analysis) in Sheets to pull data there.
2. To use Google Cloud Storage as a trampoline, export BQ data to GCS first then import to Sheets.

Comment: The first approach is limited to 10,000 rows.

Answer (score 1):

I got around this by having 3 sheets in total (but it can expanded if needed):
Using Data > Data Connectors > BigQuery in the tool bar (for Sheets #1 and #2)

- Sheet #1 that queried the top 10,000 records -> `SELECT ... FROM <TABLE> LIMIT 10000`
- Sheet #2 that queried the bottom 10,000 records -> `SELECT ... FROM <TABLE> LIMIT 10000 OFFSET 10000`
- Sheet #3 which essentially unions those sheets together with google sheets functionality: In cell a1: =importrange("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/...","'Sheet #1'!A1:n10000")
  In cell a10001: =importrange("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/...","'Sheet #2'!A2:n10000") (<- notice the A2 instead of A1 to ignore the header row)

To "refresh" Sheet #3 just individually refresh Sheet #1 and #2. This is more of a "hack" than a scalable solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is another method for your reference. However, the speed of execution is relatively slow.

Step1 : **Install the Cloud SDK**:
Command Line Interface and configure environment variables and default dataset name etc.

[Cloud SDK: Command Line Interface](https://cloud.google.com/sdk?hl=en)

Step2 : **Use bq command**:
one of the key parameters is "max_rows", you can define the size of table that you want to export.

```
 bq --format=csv --max_rows=xxxxxx -use_legacy_sql=false "select * from dataset.table"
```

[bq command-line tool reference](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/bq-cli-reference?hl=en#bq_extract)